# Parameterize Agent Based Simulation (OOP-Question)

Tags: object-oriented, frameworks, simulation

I'd like to hear my fellow programmer's thoughts on the issue of parametrizing agent based simulations:

Consider:

- Simulation core, including geometry, collision tests, some rules
- Different agents (modelled in OOP-fashion: has-a, is-a, abstract interfaces)
- Agents have different sensors, different actors, different controllers, ... All connected together by references/pointers and accessed using abstract interfaces.

So essentially, each agent is composed of an ownership tree (agent owns sensors, controller, actors), superimposed by a dataflow-graph (sensor connected to controller, connected to actor). The tree, the graph plus the parametrization of the things together form a **simulation setup**. Running a simulation amounts to:

- Read in simulation setup
- Instantiate a bunch of objects, parametrize and connect them together to form the tree and the graph
- Run simulation
- Output some data (statistics, signals, whatever)

The question is how best to save the simulation setup, and how to instantiate & parametrize stuff.

Requirements (some of them conflicting):

1. The parametrization should probably be structured along the ownership tree, as it feels most natural.
2. A lot of times I'd like to instantiate a bunch of similar agents with just the 1 or 2 parameters changed between instances. That needs to be easy.
3. I'd like to keep parametrization and code close together. When experimenting with algorithms that are affected by parametrization, I wouldn't want the changes to be spread out over too many places.
4. Conversely, I'd like to keep parametrization out of the code, so that it's easy to automate simulation runs in order to systematically sweep through parameter spaces.
5. Parameters have meta-data: type, value range, physical unit, textual description, logical dependencies (e.g. if you specify X you must not specify Y)
6. Parameters not only affect data (member variables) but also code (usage of a particular specialization of the abstract base)

---

Now my colleges and me are tasked with building a new agent-based simulation:

- Do you know any frameworks / libraries / techniques?
- Are any patterns applicable? Best practises?
- Meta-programming?
- Abandon OOP altogether?

Looking forward to your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

## DSL

Reconsider the domain-specific language approach. From your description that sounds most appropriate. It is a lot of work, but if this is going to be a long-lived simulation system the effort may be worthwhile.

## Blob

If this is not going to be a long-lived system, consider just dumping parameters into JSON (or XML, or name-value pairs, et al) blobs in a database keyed by agent type and scenario name. Simple serialization, in other words. Write a scenario editor to maintain the data. I'm guessing here that the results of the simulation are far more important than the beauty of the simulation code, as long as it does what you need it to without excess hassle/tedium.

Comment: DSL - I already thought about embedding LUA or a similar language to read in configuration files.

Comment: Blob - Interesting idea: You mean to (1) leave the defaults in the source code; then (2) auto-generate the configuration by "saving" or by scraping parameters from the source; (3) editing or merging the generated config-files and (4) load them back into the simulation.

Comment: @edgar.holleis yes. not all data has to be extremely relationally structured to be useful. This struck me as a case where all you really need to do is edit the simulation parameters, then store and rehydrate them easily.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know any frameworks / libraries / techniques?

Find a better language.  Compiling doesn't help.  Repeating yourself in XML doesn't help.  Writing a DSL doesn't help.

Use an interpreted language.  Python, Smalltalk, Lisp leap to mind.

> Are any patterns applicable? Best practises?

Yes.  Use an intepreted language.

> Meta-programming?

Avoid this.

> Abandon OOP altogether?

OOP was invented expressly for this purpose.  Read the history of [Simula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) and related languages.

If you can't do simulation in OOP, something very bad is happening around the edges of the project and leading you astray.

Comment: Do you mean embedding a language like LUA into the simulation framework? Or do you mean rewriting the simulation in an interpreted language? In how far would the latter help with parametrizing the simulation?

Comment: @edgar.holleis: Yes. "rewriting the simulation in an interpreted language".  "how far would the latter help..." Completely.  100%.  A dynamic, interpreted language is it's own parameterization.  Please follow a few tutorials for Python, Lisp, Smalltalk, whatever to see how your problem ceases to exist if you use an interpreted language.

Comment: @S.Lott: You suggest making use of Code=Data and meta-programming to create a domain specific configuration language. That mostly solves the low-level stuff (parsing, instantiation). However it doesn't address the problem of how to structure and organize the data along with the code. Would you share any thoughts on that?

Comment: @edgar.holleis: "You suggest making use of Code=Data and meta-programming".  Not at all.  Code==code.  But interpreted code is more flexible than compiled code.  You have many, many layers of code with varying degrees of configurability.  "how to structure and organize the data"?  There's nothing in the question about this; please open another question with some actual details.

Comment: @S.Lott: "interpreted code is more flexible than compiled code": I fail to see your point. Do you mean dynamically typed language vs. statically typed language? What makes interpreted code more flexible? Especially in a scientific environment where it's perfectly fine to keep the compiler close.

Comment: "dynamically typed language vs. statically typed language" can be more flexible.  The compiler (and the need to read and parse a configuration file) slows down your development and leads to complex questions like this.  If you use an interpreted language, the high-level code for your simulation *is* your configuration. Reading and parsing eliminated.  (Much as I dislike it -- this may be more appropriate for chat rather than comments.)

Comment: @S.Lott: "structure and organize the data": Let me try to explain: Halve of the problem is how to get parametrization from some data-file (maybe even the source-file) into the running simulation. The other half deals with how to organize the the parametrization data along with the bits of code that need it: Make it work for people who run scenarios, people who optimize parametrization and people who code features that need new parameters (roughly a third each).

Comment: @edgar.holleis: All laudable goals.  Without details, it's hard to show how to accomplish that.  What's important is this.  The compiler introduces a huge cost and complexity that only has value when performance is **critical**.  RDBMS.  OS.  Network.  Most applications (i.e. simulation applications) don't require compiled code.  An interpreted language has numerous benefits with no cost other than performance.  It can **greatly** simplify the code by eliminating parts of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I see how xml parsing can get painful, but have you thought about document models? (JSON based for example).

If you are going down this path, there are databases that are document based (couchDB) which can help in storing/querying this data. And with decent normalization of your data, you could build a system with following components:
 1. Manages data storage / parsing / analysis / reporting
 2. A component that handles generating simulation samples from this data. (For example, you might want all data that are permutations of X:Y)

The biggest problem I have seen in configuration oriented systems is that sooner or later people start losing out on separation of concerns / SRP. This way, data gets messy and so on. Once you build a data management system, these difficulties should reduce.

Also, at a team level you should come to an understanding that this is something that is very necessary. The other end of this is unlimited number of C files that are hard to maintain/edit etc. Data in code has usually resulted in trouble.

Comment: Databases are almost certainly not the way to go. We need the parametrization close to the code. You see, almost all usage scenarios for agent-based simulation involve changing some of its code - like creating a new type of controller and test the resulting agent against agents using the old controller. So 90% of the users are in fact programmers. We use source-control, branching and merging and parametrization-data should live in source-control as well.

Answer (score 0):

How you parameterize is tightly linked to how your overall simulation is designed.

One approach that I have used in this situation goes something like this.

The components you model should all derive from some common class that your simulation engine can deal with. These include methods for simulation (event handling and timing), and communication (message passing).

The simulation engine is responsible for timing and event management, and also for message passing.

The class interface should have a standard set of methods so that elements can be connected together. All interactions between your model elements should go through the standard communication methods.

A simulation engine that I have successfully used is [DEVS-Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/devs-suitesim/).